# My form validations work but seem to be submitting blank sometimes with a hack

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, validation

My form has JavaScript validations that return errors and stop form submissions when a field is empty. ""

I also have a PHP validation on the backend checking for any empty fields.

The submission sends an email with the fields.

In testing all validations work. The form submits with all information when filled in correctly.

I am getting a blank email about once a day. How is a submission bypassing my JavaScript and PHP validations?

My form:

```
<form id="itsp-form" method="post" action="http://www.website.com/save_itsp.php">
<label class="custom">Company name</label>
<input id="company_name" type="text" name="company_name" />

<label class="custom">Company URL</label>
<input id="company_url" type="text" name="company_url" />

<label class="custom">Company address</label>
<input id="company_address" type="text" name="company_address" />

<label class="custom">Type of business</label>
<select id="type_of_business[]" name="type_of_business[]" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="enterprise">Business sector/Enterprise</option>
  <option value="residential">Residential</option>
  <option value="wholesale">Wholesale VoIP Carrier</option>
  <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>

<label class="custom">Areas served</label>
<select id="areas_served[]" name="areas_served[]" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="USA">USA</option>
  <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
  <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>

<br />

<label class="custom">Sales contact</label><br />
<h4>Name</h4>
  <input id="sales_name" type="text" name="sales_name" />
<h4>Phone</h4>
  <input type="text" name="sales_phone" />
<h4>Email</h4>
  <input type="text" name="sales_email" />

<br />

<label class="custom">Testing contact</label><br />
<h4>Name</h4>
  <input id="testing_name" type="text" name="testing_name" />
<h4>Phone</h4>
  <input type="text" name="testing_phone" />
<h4>Email</h4>
  <input type="text" name="testing_email" />

<br />

<label class="custom">Switch Platform</label>
<select id="switch_platform[]" name="switch_platform[]" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="asterisk">Asterisk</option>
  <option value="broadsoft">Broadsoft</option>
  <option value="metaswitch">Metaswitch</option>
  <option value="sipx">SipX/eZuce</option>
  <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>

<label class="custom">Interested In Testing</label>
<select id="interested_in_testing[]" name="interested_in_testing[]" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="atas">ATAs</option>
  <option value="ip_phones">IP Phones</option>
  <option value="gateways">Gateways</option>
  <option value="ip_pbx">IP PBX</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
<div id="errors"></div>
</div>
 <script>
  $('#submit').click(function() {
    $('.error').hide();

    var hasError = false;
    var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;

    if (($("#company_name").val() == '') || ($("#type_of_business[]").val() == '')) {
       $("#errors").after('<span class="error">Please enter your Company name.</span>');
       hasError = true;
    }
    if (($("#company_url").val() == '') || ($("#company_address").val() == '')) {
       $("#errors").after('<span class="error">Please enter your Company information.</span>');
       hasError = true;
    }
    if ($("#areas_served[]").length < 0) {
       $("#errors").after('<span class="error">Please enter your Areas served.</span>');
       hasError = true;
    }
    if ($("#type_of_business[]").length < 0) {
       $("#errors").after('<span class="error">Please enter your Type of business.</span>');
       hasError = true;
    }
    if ($("#sales_name").val() == '') {
       $("#errors").after('<span class="error">Please enter your Sales contact information.</span>');
       hasError = true;
    }
    if ($("#testing_name").val() == '') {
       $("#errors").after('<span class="error">Please enter your Tester contact information</span>');
       hasError = true;
    }
    if ($("#switch_platform[]").length < 0) {
       $("#errors").after('<span class="error">Please enter your Switch platform</span>');
       hasError = true;
    }
    if ($("#interested_in_testing[]").length < 0) {
       $("#errors").after('<span class="error">Please enter your Testing interests.</span>');
       hasError = true;
    }
  if(hasError == true) { return false; }
});
```

My PHP file:

```
function died($error) {
// your error code can go here
echo "We are very sorry, but there were blank fields found with the form you
   submitted. ";
$link_address = 'http://www.website.com/url/itsp';
echo "<a href='".$link_address."'>Click to Go Back<br/></a>";
die();
}


if (isset($_POST['company_name'])) 
{
$errors = "";

//validate and sanitize company name
if ($_POST['company_name'] != "")
{
  $_POST['company_name'] = filter_var($_POST['company_name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $company_name = $_POST['company_name'];
}
else 
died();

//validate and sanitize company url
if ($_POST['company_url'] != "")
{
  $_POST['company_url'] = filter_var($_POST['company_url'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $company_url = $_POST['company_url'];
}
else
    died();
//validate and sanitize company address
if ($_POST['company_address'] != "")
{
  $_POST['company_address'] = filter_var($_POST['company_address'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $company_address = $_POST['company_address'];
}
else
    died();
if (is_array($_POST['type_of_business']) && !empty($_POST['type_of_business'])) {
    $type_of_business_val = array();
    foreach($_POST['type_of_business'] as $val) {
        $type_of_business_val[] = $val;
    }
    $type_of_business = implode(',', $type_of_business_val);
}
else
    died();
if (is_array($_POST['areas_served']) && !empty($_POST['areas_served'])) {
    $areas_served_val = array();
    foreach($_POST['areas_served'] as $val) {
        $areas_served_val[] = $val;
    }
    $areas_served = implode(',', $areas_served_val);
}
else
    died();
//validate and sanitize sales name
if ($_POST['sales_name'] != "")
{
  $_POST['sales_name'] = filter_var($_POST['sales_name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $sales_name = $_POST['sales_name'];
}
else
    died();
//validate and sanitize sales email
if ($_POST['sales_email'] != "")
{
  $sales_email = filter_var($_POST['sales_email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
  if (!filter_var($sales_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $errors .= "$sales_email is <strong>NOT</strong> a valid email address.<br/><br/>";
  }
}
else
    died();
//validate and sanitize sales phone number
if ($_POST['sales_phone'] != "")
{
  $_POST['sales_phone'] = filter_var($_POST['sales_phone'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $sales_phone = $_POST['sales_phone'];
}
else
    died();
//validate and sanitize testing name
if ($_POST['testing_name'] != "")
{
  $_POST['testing_name'] = filter_var($_POST['testing_name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $testing_name = $_POST['testing_name'];
}
else
    died();
//validate and sanitize testing email
if ($_POST['testing_email'] != "")
{
  $testing_email = filter_var($_POST['testing_email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
  if (!filter_var($testing_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $errors .= "$testing_email is <strong>NOT</strong> a valid email address.<br/><br/>";
  }
}
else
    died();
if ($_POST['testing_phone'] != "")
{
  $_POST['testing_phone'] = filter_var($_POST['testing_phone'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $testing_phone = $_POST['testing_phone'];
}
else
    died();
if (is_array($_POST['switch_platform']) && !empty($_POST['switch_platform'])) 
{
    $switch_platform_val = array();
    foreach($_POST['switch_platform'] as $val) {
        $switch_platform_val[] = $val;
    }
    $switch_platform = implode(',', $switch_platform_val);
}
else
    died();

if (is_array($_POST['interested_in_testing']) && !empty($_POST['interested_in_testing'])) {
    $interested_in_testing_val = array();
    foreach($_POST['interested_in_testing'] as $val) {
        $interested_in_testing_val[] = $val;
    }
    $interested_in_testing = implode(',', $interested_in_testing_val);
}
else
    died();
 }
 /************** End Validations *******************/

 /*****Email*****/
$to = "email";
$subject = "New ITSP Submission";
$message1 = "A new ITSP has submitted their information:
<br/>Company Name: " . $company_name . "
<br/>Company URL: " . $company_url . "
<br/>Company Address: " . $company_address . "
<br/>Type of Business: " . $type_of_business . "
<br/>Area(s) Served: " . $areas_served . "
<br/>Sales Name: " . $sales_name . "
<br/>Sales Email: " . $sales_email . "
<br/>Sales Phone: " . $sales_phone . "
<br/>Testing Name: " . $testing_name . "
<br/>Testing Email: " . $testing_email . "
<br/>Testing Phone: " . $testing_phone . "
<br/>Switch Platform: " . $switch_platform . "
<br/>Interested In Testing: " . $interested_in_testing ;


$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message1,$headers);
header("location: http://www.website.com/dir/itsp-confirmation/");
```

Comment: the string "    " (whitespace, so empty but length > 1) will pass, try `trim()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't call your function died() if the email validator fails but only if the email is empty.

And your FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL can return a empty string.
For exemple if your $_POST['sales_email'] is equals to a whitespace or any character that your email filter remove, you'll get an empty string.

Try this:

```
if ($_POST['sales_email'] != "")
{
  $sales_email = filter_var($_POST['sales_email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
  if (!filter_var($sales_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $errors .= "$sales_email is <strong>NOT</strong> a valid email address.<br/><br/>";
      died();
  }
}
else
    died();
```

Comment: For the select boxes, how would they not validate? The 'switch_platform' is checking if it is empty. Yet the hack email shows up with nothing in that field.

Answer (score 0):

You can add required in your input field in your form to make sure that a field has got text in before it is submitted. Also filter_var() may be returning false if fields don't pass the validation and may be showing up blank in your emails as a result.

Comment: If filter_var() returns false the user is routed to a page telling them the error message and a link to go back to try again. The email will not send. I tested it.